# Formulating extended euclidean algorithm- derivation required

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know the extended euclidean algorithm by working myself backward from the euclidean algorithm to find the GCD. I'm confused with the extended euclidean algorithm as given in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). How is this process derived and why are we introducing new variables s and t? How is this process derived from working backwards with the standard euclidean algorithm? And how does the computation work now that we have $s_0, s_1, t_0, t_1$, which is neither intuitive nor any explanation is given anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very hard, but it indeed requires some explanations.

What is easy to prove by induction (of order $2$) is this:

> In the  Euclidean algorithm for the g.c.d. of two positive integers $a$ and $b$, denote $q_i$ and $r_i$ the quotient and the remainder in the $i$-th Euclidean division. Then all remainders satisfy a Bézout's relation:
>   $$r_i=s_ia+t_i b\qquad(s_i, t_i\in\mathbf Z).$$

Indeed the first division: $\;b=q_1a+r_1$ can be read as $r_1=b-q_1a$ (supposing $b>a$).
 The second division: $\;a=q_2 r_1+r_2$ yields
$$ r_2=a-q_2r_1=a-q_2(b-q_1a)=(1+q_1q_2)a -q_2b. $$

Suppose now the assertion is true for $r_{i-1}$ and $r_i\;(i>2)$. From the equalities
\begin{align}
r_{i-1}&=q_ir_i+ r_{i+1}, \\
r_{i-1}&=s_{i-1}a+t_{i-1}b, \\
r_i&=s_ia+t_ib,
\end{align}
we deduce that
$$r_{i+1}=(s_{i-1}-q_is_i)a+(r_{i-1}-q_irs_i)b$$
whence the recursive relations of the *extended Euclidean algorithm*:

> Initialisation (coefficients for $a$ and $b$):
>   $$b:\quad (0,1),\qquad a:\quad (1,0)$$
>   $$\text{Recurrence relations: }\qquad s_{i+1}=s_{i-1}-q_is_i,\qquad t_{i+1}=t_{i-1}-q_it_i\hspace{12em}$$

Comment: if $r_i=s_ia+t_ib$ then how does $r_{i-1}=q_i r_i+r_{i+1} \implies\ r_{i-1}=s_{i-1}a+t_{i-1}b$ ?

Comment: The conclusion of your implication is part of the inductive hypothesis (I use a recursion of order $2$ – I should have been more explicit).

Comment: I don't know about recursion or anything like that, should I study something else before understanding this?

Comment: You've never seen a proof by induction?

Comment: I have, but the recursion of order 2 is what I meant I didn't understand.

Comment: This happens when establishing a case requires it is supposed true for the two previous cases. This requires initialising for the first two cases. It's a form of strong induction.